# How to use EntityManager efficiently?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

I've read a lot of books and articles about Java persistence lately and the more I read the more confused I am about **how to use JPA correctly** and **efficiently**.

Right now I have simple **service layer** for **each type of entity** which takes care of persisting, removing, searching, etc. It acquires the **EntityManagerFactory** from a **singleton** util class, **creates** an **EntityManager**, **does the transaction**, and then **closes** the **EntityManager**. The EMF is only closed on application shutdown. If I'm understanding correctly, **by closing the EntityManager**, **all my objects (related to it) become detached**. By changing any value in the objects, they are not getting persisted, so I presume this is the case.

In a book I've read that I should make the service classes **@Stateless beans**, and **inject** the **EntityManager** as **@PersistenceContext** in them. That way I'll have the same amount of EntityManagers as many service classes I have *(or is it smart enough to inject only one?)*. I assume that there can be such cases when one object is handled by more EntityManagers, which is inefficient, maybe could lead to errors. Can I make the EntityManager a singleton, which holds and manages everything, and lives through the whole application lifetime just like the EMF?

As I've learned, the EntityManager should be closed after each transaction, but then I'm confused about the managed part:

In my case:

```
Car car = CarService.findOneById(somelong); //this method returns an already detached object, nothing is ever in managed state
car.setColor("yellow");
CarService.update(car); //updates the db
```

(This is not even problematic for me yet, only an unnecessary bad, until LAZY fetching comes into play.)

How I think it should work:

```
Car car = CarService.findOneById(somelong); //does not close the EM
car.setColor("yellow"); //by this call the EM detects(?) and persists the change
```

What are the ways to achieve that, and which is considered the best practice? If you could give me an example of each layer, I'd be grateful.

Thank you in advance!

P.S.: I know the question is really broad, but I hope someone can erase the questionmarks from my head.

Comment: This is rather broad, and I'm not sure you'll get a definitive answer. I personally use Spring's `@Transactional` aspect to handle transaction boundaries for me declaratively and don't manually open or close entity managers.

Comment: Do you use Spring or Java EE?

Comment: @ArtemNovikov I'm using Java EE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a book I've read that I should make the service classes @Stateless beans, and inject the EntityManager as @PersistenceContext in them. That way I'll have the same amount of EntityManagers as many service classes I have

No. You'll get an persistence context that is bound to the current transaction. In short, the container will do what you're doing by yourself, except that if service A calls service B, which calls service C, which calls service D, and they all share the same transaction context, they will also get the same persistence context. And the persistence context will be closed when the transaction is closed.

```
Car car = CarService.findOneById(somelong); //does not close the EM
car.setColor("yellow"); //by this call the EM detects(?) and persists the change
```

This will automatically make the color change persistent, as long as you're doing that inside a transaction, and not outside.

From your description, what I understand is that your services are not really services. They're just DAOs: they persist and find a single type of entity, and don't contain any business logic. That's not where transactions should be handled. Transactions should be handled in the real, business service layer, which implements transactional use-cases of your application.

For example, let's say you develop a banking application. A typical use-case is not to decrease the balance of an account. Or to increase the balance of an account. Or to increase the bank's own account balance. A typical use case would be to implement a transfer of money between accounts. This means that a single transaction must:

- find the emitter account
- find the receiver account
- check that the transfer can be done
- compute a percentage that the bank earns for doing the transfer
- decrease the emitter account balance
- add the earned amount to the bank account
- increase the receiver acount balance
- add the transfer operation to the emitter account
- add the transfer operation to the receiver account

This use-case will use several DAOs: AccountDAO, OperationDAO, BankAccountDAO, etc., but everything should be done in a single transaction. And this whole transaction will use a unique persistence context, where all the entities are managed, and thus where all changes are automatically persisted without having to call `update()` on any DAO.

Comment: You are right, I missed/mixed the DAO and the service layer. Each service layer call then should create an EM, start a transaction, call the DAO-s by passing the EM to them, then finish transaction and close the EM?

Comment: No. The service should be a stateless bean, and should not deal with the EM. Being a stateless bean, a transaction will automatically be started when it's called from the outside. Then it will call a DAO, passing functional arguments, if any. The DAO is a stateless bean, or a simple CDI bean, where the EM is injected. The EM is bound to the transaction started when calling the service. So if the service calls three DAOs, each with EM being injected, they all will share the same persistence context, and the same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is a complete answer you expect, but just a few tips:

Creating EMF is a hard operation, while creating EM is a lightweight one. Therefore yes, EMF is recommended to be a singleton and it's thread safe.

EM are not thread safe. You are right, EM are recommended to be closed upon complete of transactions to release entities and resourses you don't need anymore, but the transaction is not necesseraly limited to just getting an object by id like in your example. You are free to get an object and do with that what you want (for ex: setting collor like in your example) and THEN closing the transaction - just do it in a special `updateCarColor` service method.

Since you are in a Java EE environment, you'd rather leave EM management to the container, which will share the same EM when you are inside the same transaction, when injecting with `@PersistenceContext`. It's done by a proxy - not a real EM gets injected into the `EntityManager em` field, but a proxy. This proxy will pass your calls to a shared EM. If there is no active transaction, it will create a new shared EM and then pass the calls to it.